# Why assigning an interface to a Record results in index signature error?

Tags: typescript, types

In the example below, the first call to log() with userType works fine, while the second call with userInterface results in this error:

> S2345: Argument of type 'UserInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.   Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'UserInterface'

```
function log(item: Record<string, unknown>) {
  console.log(item);
}

export type UserType = {
  name: string;
};

interface UserInterface {
  name: string;
}

const userType: UserType = { name: 'John' };
const userInterface: UserInterface = { name: 'John' };

log(userType);
log(userInterface);
```

Comment: This is the subject of [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) whereby interfaces are not allowed to have implicit index signatures while structurally equivalent object types are allowed to have them.